# How to get the sum of hours per week by activity using the sql time datatype?

Tags: sql-server

Hopefully, someone can help me. I'm trying to generate a report to list all the worked hours per department per activity on a weekly basis.

My table contains the following information

[image]

and I want to accomplish the following

[image]

I've been trying to create a query, this is what I have so far.

```
select id, Departmentname, Week, Activity, 
substring(cast(convert(Time, dateadd(millisecond, sum(datediff(millisecond, 
0, cast([Time] as datetime))), 0), 108) as CHAR(5)),0,9) AS 'Time'
from Time where Week LIKE '%' AND Departmentname LIKE '%' GROUP BY Week, 
Activity, Departmentname, id
```

Comment: What is `id` and do you really need to have it in your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: id is product key. I don't want to GROUP BY id but if I don't include it in the GROUP BY it states that it is not contained in the aggregate function

Comment: Take it out of `SELECT`.

Comment: Take it out of the select, do you mind explaining why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need only grouping. Just time should be converted to int to count totals

```
select
    [Week], Dept, Activity
    , [time] = isnull(right('0' + cast(total / 60 as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(total % 60 as varchar(2)), 2), '00:00')
from (
    select
        [Week], Dept, Activity
        , total = sum(cast(left([time], 2) as int) * 60 + cast(right([time], 2) as int))
    from
        myTable
    group by [Week], Dept, Activity
) t
```

Comment: Hey thanks, for the quick reply. This query is replacing the NULL values with 00:00 which is good but it is not performing any sum operations on the times

Comment: How do you think what does `sum` function do in the inner query? Recheck query please. It calculates total time and converts back to time format replacing nulls

Comment: dfghj 00:00
dfghj 00:00
joden 00:00
Pens 04:00
Pens 04:00
Pens 04:00
Pens 04:00
Pens 04:00
Pens 04:00
test         04:00

Comment: that's what the query is returning. I wanted the null values to appear as 00:00 and I wanted to Sum all the activies by week

Comment: Remove `Days` from `GROUP BY` and either remove it from `SELECT`, or put it in `MIN`.

Comment: @TonyBatista, I missed that you have different days for Pens. That's why it's better to provide your sample data as DML, not an image. So we could troubleshoot.

Comment: @uzi Sorry about that, next time I ask a question I'll be sure to provide more details and a more clear explanation of the problem. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @TonyBatista, no problem. Happy to help